# hadoop teragen doesn't store file in the directory I specify

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I did the following:

```
hadoop jar /home/yarn/hadoop-2.4.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar teragen 10 /home/yarn/terasort-input
```

`teragen` executed giving me seemingly normal terminal output, but nothing in the the specified directory? what have I done wrong or where should I check?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Output files are stored in HDFS, I need to do

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

For example:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar teragen 10 terainput
```

Generates the following files in `terainput` folder, with total size of 10 x 100-byte.

```
yarn@master:~$ hadoop fs -ls terainput
Found 7 items
-rw-r--r--   2 yarn supergroup          0 2015-09-29 05:14 terainput/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   2 yarn supergroup        200 2015-09-29 05:14 terainput/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   2 yarn supergroup        200 2015-09-29 05:14 terainput/part-m-00001
-rw-r--r--   2 yarn supergroup        100 2015-09-29 05:14 terainput/part-m-00002
-rw-r--r--   2 yarn supergroup        200 2015-09-29 05:13 terainput/part-m-00003
-rw-r--r--   2 yarn supergroup        200 2015-09-29 05:14 terainput/part-m-00004
-rw-r--r--   2 yarn supergroup        100 2015-09-29 05:14 terainput/part-m-00005
```